# ESRI's shapefile to Matlab

Tags: matlab, esri, shapefile

I am looking for a function to read/write points, lines and polygons from ESRI's shapefile format (as used in Arcview) for use in Matlab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Matlab mapping toolbox, use the `shaperead` [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/shaperead.html)

For example download the NOAA Interstate Highway shape file [here](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/catalog/transportation/html/interst.htm), extract and then read data into Matlab using the function, `S = shaperead('in101503.shp');`

Answer (score 7):

If you do not have the Matlab mapping toobox, the very useful [m_map package](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html) now has an m_shaperead() function which does a good job of reading shapefiles.

```
X = m_shaperead('filename'); % for filename.(dbf,shp,...)
```